# Why does pyrolysis activate carbon?

Tags: organic-chemistry, pyrolysis

I am doing a project that involves activating carbon. The method my team is using is simply to heat it within the range of 400-500°C, and then testing for activity by using a dye.

Why does simply heating it (without any additional reactants like zinc chloride and so on) activate it?